# Disable all other Switches when one is enabled

Tags: android

I have three `Switches`. What I want is when I click one the other two to become disabled.

What I have done is setting a setCheckedListener to each one of them and when I check one I set the checked state of the other two to false.

The code is :

```
    @Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
    switch (compoundButton.getId()) {
        case R.id.switch_most_popular:
            mostViewedSwitch.setChecked(false);
            latestUpdatedSwitch.setChecked(false);
            break;
        case R.id.switch_most_viewed:
            mostPopularSwitch.setChecked(false);
            latestUpdatedSwitch.setChecked(false);
            break;
        case R.id.switch_latest_updated:
            mostPopularSwitch.setChecked(false);
            mostViewedSwitch.setChecked(false);
            break;
        default:
            Log.i(TAG, "no checked Switch ");
            break;
    }
}
```

What happens with this code is that I need to times to touch the switch. The first time disables the one is that is checked and the second time it enables the one I have checked.

What should I change to the above code so I can achieve the behavior I want? Or is there any other option for this use case ? 
Thanks

Comment: see my answer below.

Comment: lol question. Did you try use google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for disable switch used this

```
mostViewedSwitch.setEnabled(false);
latestUpdatedSwitch.setEnabled(false);
```

not

```
mostViewedSwitch.setChecked(false);
latestUpdatedSwitch.setChecked(false);
```

because it's not checkbox it's switch.

Comment: @Mes glad to help you.